# Case insensitive string compare with linq-to-sql and linq-to-objects

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

see also [Differences between LINQ to Objects and LINQ to SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718195/differences-between-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql-queries)

We are using the **some** queries over our **database** and our **in memory objects**.

What is the best way of doing an insensitive string compare with linq-to-sql so that?

- It runs fast on SQL Server
- The same query expression can be used with linq-to-objects to get the same result

Using

```
a.ToLowerInvariant() == b.ToLowerInvariant()
```

at least gets the same results, but it does not get processed on SQL server as far as I can tell, so can be a lot slower then

```
a == b
```

Comment: @Rbarry How does a Stored Procedure help with running a query over our in memory objects?

Comment: Ah. Good point (duh).  Never mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in linq to sql, but you could just use the ToUpperInvariant() method of string before compareing.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is it will not get process on sql server as far as a know, so a lot of rows will get dragged over the nextwork.  As you were writing the answer I was trying ToLowerInveriant() that at lest gets my unit tests to pass.

Answer (score 7):

Case sensitivity in your SQL database is determined by the collation setting. By default, I think most databases are case insensitive, so you should check whether you actually need to handle case sensitivity explicitly.

In a collation setting of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` - **CI** stands for case insensitive and **AS** stands for accent sensitive.

Unfortunately, Linq-to-Sql ignores the extra parameters of `String.Compare()` so you won't be able to explicitly set the case sensitivity to compare with. It will work with linq to objects however.

If you use a case sensitive collation, you could use something like `SqlMethods.Like(field, "string")` to use a LIKE query - which is case insensitive -, but that doesn't translate into linq to objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the list of supported string operations in LINQ to SQL, which would obviously work in LINQ to objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx

I personally haven't evaluated each for performance, but ToLower and ToUpper aren't supported in LINQ to SQL, so it seems like Compare is a good candidate.  You can explore the translated SQL by using a tool like LINQPad, which has a free version and translates a query into database SQL, and see how it runs against the DB.

Also, LINQ to Objects probably differs so what's good for one may not be good for the other...

Comment: we need to run the some "filter" on stored data and live data, so using the some linq query lead to nice code.  If only it did the same thing!