# How do I run a set of nUnit tests with two different setups?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

(Sorry for the unclear title, please edit it if you can come up with a better one)

I wish to run the same tests over two different data stores, I can create the data stores in the Setup() method.

So should I have a super class that contains all the tests and an abstract `SetUp()` method, then have a subclass for each data store?

Or is there a better way?

See "[Case insensitive string compare with linq-to-sql and linq-to-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388022/case-insensitive-string-compare-with-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-objects)" for what I am testing.

Comment: You can use test fixture attributes with parameters, e.g. [TestFixture(2)]
[TestFixture(1)]. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35015148/496032

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution is this.

All your test-cases are in an abstract class for example in the TestBase-class. For example:

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected string SetupMethodWas = "";

    [Test]
    public void ExampleTest()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(SetupMethodWas);    
    }

    // other test-cases
}
```

Then you create two sub-classes for each setup. So each sub-class will be run a individual with it-setup method and also all inherited test-methods.

```
[TestFixture]
class TestA : TestBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SetupMethodWas = "SetupOf-A";    
    }
}
[TestFixture]
class TestB : TestBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SetupMethodWas = "TestB";
    }
}
```

This works wonderful. However for simpler tests [parameterized tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5) are a better solution