# SpecFlow - how to test all features several times? (once for each browser)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I have huge web app; will be creating lots of SpecFlow tests (plan to use NUnit as a testrunner)
I would like to do **complete** test (feature by feature) for each browser, like this:

*recreate test db*
**1) test all features (Firefox)**

   *recreate test db*
**2) test all features (Chrome)**

   *recreate test db*
**3) test all features (IE)**

**4) Show 3 separate test report files** (if this is local testing) or mark TeamCity build failed if any of the tests failed for any browser

If I could supply browser name to the testrunner (as external parameter) this would solve the problem, I would just run it from batch file, calling nunit-console.exe 3 times, supplying different browser name each time, like this:

```
nunit-console.exe /browserName=Chrome /labels /out=TestResult.txt /xml=TestResult.xml bin\Debug\MyApp.AcceptanceTests.dll
```

The problem is: it doesn't look like nunit-console.exe is able to accept custom parameters and pass these to the test; would it be possible to do it at all?

Is there any other way to accomplish the task? Perhaps, I should use another test framework and/or testrunner?

Please note my question is not duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471198/multiple-browsers-tests-using-webinatorselenium-specflow-and-nunit) (I want to run all features/scenarios using certain browser, before switching to another one)

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround: msbuild could store browser name in a text file, then call nunit-console.exe (and unit test would take browser file from there, creating appropriate web driver to use during the test)

I still hope there is a way to pass parameter to the test through nunit-console.exe