# Browser emulation - Which Selenium do I need?

Tags: selenium

I am struggling to get a `RemoteWebDriver` to work.

I wondered whether I needed `Selenium RC`, so I installed that with `Nuget` and noticed that `DefaultSelenium` takes a path to the browser as a parameter.

I am getting a bit overwhelmed with all the different libraries available for `Selenium` - but what I want is to be able to run against a host of browsers (android/chrome/firefox, etc) without those browsers necessarily existing on the machine that `Selenium` is running on.

Is that possible? And if so, which `Selenium` libraries would I need (I am using `VS2012` and `C#`) to acheive this?

I was trying to achieve this with RemoteWebDriver with a range of different DesiredCapabilites, rather than using ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, especially considering this is a new project, 100% absolutely positively use the WebDriver API. So you only need the WebDriver NuGet package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/

You will need the IEDriver package too, if you intend to test against IE, and the same for Chrome/Safari etc.

I say this because the WebDriver is constantly being developed on, maintained, and improved. It has a better *cleaner* and nicer API, and will be more stable in the long run.

RC is deprecated. Although I believe the developer's intend to still fix any *bugs*, new features and improvements won't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this has some good answers : [Run Selenium tests in multiple browsers one after another from C# NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028926/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-one-after-another-from-c-sharp-nunit). I personal use IWebDriver and Selenium RC and test it like that. Cause i have a lot of tests and testing in every browser is to much for me.