# WebDriver. How can I run test in multiple browsers using C#?

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-rc

Please Help Me,

I  use selenium WebDriver for automatically web tests. How can I make it run in multiple browsers in parallel using C#?

If there is a way to make this with a configuration file ?  would be ideal.

Comment: I found how to run tests in multiple browsers using C#, [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388489/how-do-i-run-a-set-of-nunit-tests-with-two-different-setups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/).

See [this blog post describing the approach](http://slmoloch.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/design-of-selenium-tests-for-aspnet_19.html)