# Run TestFixture multiple times using Nunit or Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins

I have a TestFixture which contains multiple tests. I want to run this TestFixture multiple times to collect some statistics but can't seem to find a reasonable way. The RepeatAttribute cannot be used on a TestFixture.

I can use Nunit or Jenkins (with nunit plugin). Any ideas? Otherwise I would end up coding it into the test or use weird batch scripting.

Comment: The best way might be to put the tests you need statistics for in an entirely separate assembly. That way, you can execute the test runner against the assembly multiple times (which should be simple).

Answer (score 6):

As Steve says, a parameterized fixture works, but if you want to run your test hundreds of times, it would get fairly tedious to copy and paste that many attributes.

A better option in NUnit is to use the [TestFixtureSource](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/TestFixtureSource-Attribute) attribute on your fixture. For example, the following code will run your test fixture 100 times;

```
[TestFixtureSource("TestData")]
public class MultipleRunFixture
{
    int _counter;

    public MultipleRunFixture(int counter)
    {
        _counter = counter;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> TestData =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // TODO: Add your test code here
        Assert.Pass($"Test run {_counter}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a paramterized fixture: then the fixture would run as many times as you have added the attribute:

```
[TestFixture(4)]
[TestFixture(3)]
[TestFixture(2)]
[TestFixture(1)]
public class MyTestFixture
{       
    public MyTestFixture(int counter)
    {        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steve and Rob for the answers. All of them are good options but I tried another approach and it turned out to be the best solution for my case. So just putting it here for anyone else who stumbles upon it.

I created a Jenkins job for that test fixture and used a cron time to repeat the test regularly, say every 2 minutes. This way, Jenkins ran the job many times and even collected the stats for me (e.g. test failure rate).